# Sbt assembly hangs on my Mac

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have had this problem since the day I started using assembly . sbt assembly (for any project) never completes on my Mac. It just hangs at the last step .  For this one reason . I transfer my code to a Linux box and build there .  Anyone else has experienced this ?  . Any ideas on how I can go about debugging ? . I had Lion with Java 1.6.0_37  . Now upgraded to Mountain Lion

Comment: Any log oddities? It's hard to say something without, say, heapdump.

Comment: the last packaging step takes about 45-50 mins actually. Whereas on linux, it is done in 3-5 mins

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago. Do you have anti-virus software installed? In my case it was Sophos, that tried to check the jar, while sbt was still building it, which somehow led to 100% CPU usage and the assembly task taking forever. Check your activity monitor for task other than java using large amounts of cpu time and try to deactivate them. I don't know if there is a way to keep Sophos from checking the jars, would be interesting though.

Comment: Thank you! Some Java process on my Mac took about 700 % of CPU (which I don't understand as I only have four cores) from time to time. After shutting down Sophos On-access Scanning it seems to have stopped.

Comment: The 700% are most likely due to hyper threading. Meaning you have 4 cores, but each core has 2 threads, so you have 8 virtual cores.

Comment: So basically Sophos caused a peak of more than 95% of processor usage. Anyways, I would never had figured this out on my own. Thanks!